# MUI select with label without the select having an ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui react select in a component that may be on a page multiple times.

In the [examples](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) all labelled selects use InputLabel with htmlFor that must be the id of the select.

I cannot give the select an id because id has to be unique for a page and this is a component that doesn't need to know all the id's on the page (nor anywhere in my code do I want to know about all the id's in the page).

According to the [InputLabel documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/) it doesn't even have a documented htmlFor propery.

Is it possible to label a MUI select without giving it an id?

Answer (score 1):

Same as the [html label tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label); I did the nested the Select in the InputLabel:

```
<InputLabel className="paging">
  Page:
  <Select
    value={current}
    onChange={e => changePage(e.target.value)}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'page',
      id: 'page',
    }}
  >
    {options.map(option => (
      <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
        {option}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</InputLabel>
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't run into any styling difficulties with your nested solution, then that is perfectly fine, but here's an example using a generated id that would allow you to avoid nesting the Select within the InputLabel:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

let nextIdSuffix = 1;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const CustomSelect = () => {
  const idRef = React.useRef();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  if (!idRef.current) {
    idRef.current = `CustomSelect${nextIdSuffix}`;
    nextIdSuffix++;
  }
  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor={idRef.current}>Age</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        inputProps={{
          name: idRef.current,
          id: idRef.current
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
export default CustomSelect;
```

[image: Edit generated Select id]